# Regex: Replace character between two strings (excluding the strings themselves) using sed

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, replace

I have a minor problem. I want to replace a character/single string between two strings but would like to leave the strings themselves "unharmed" by using *sed*.

The input is:

```
<hello> <world>
```

My desired output:

```
<hello>
<world>
```

My first attempt:

```
echo "<hello> <world>" | sed 's/>.</\n/g'
```

The output of it:

```
<hello
world>
```

As you can see, the ">" from "" and the "<" from "" have been removed by using my line above.

How do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: This might help: `echo "<hello> <world>" | sed -E 's/(\W) (\W)/\1\n\2/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use:

```
echo "<hello> <world>" | sed 's/>.</>\n</g'
```

This is possible all the characters you are replacing are static.

Comment: If not you can also do this by using zero-length assertions, but this depends on the version of sed you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This one works too:

```
echo "<hello> <world>" | sed 's/>./>\n/g'
```